# The "no known conversion" from const char* to an iterator error - another take

Tags: c++, string, iterator, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

I'm doing the following:

```
using namespace boost;
const char* line = // ...
size_t line_length = // ...
// ...
tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > line_tokenizer(
    line, line + line_length,
    escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
```

Expecting to use the `boost::tokenizer` constructor

```
tokenizer(Iterator first, Iterator last,
          const TokenizerFunc& f = TokenizerFunc()) 
  : first_(first), last_(last), f_(f) { }
```

but GCC 4.9.3 gives me:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char*’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >’
```

Now, I've seen a couple of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361669/1593077) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21914485/1593077) in which the answer was forgetting to `#include <algorithm>` -  but I *have* included it. Is there some other missing include, or is it another issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barry: It is succinct, complete, and not machine-verifiable, but I think it's reasonably verifiable.

Comment: It's not complete and verifiable until we can compile and reproduce your error (and then eliminate it and tell you what we did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using boost, you can do:

```
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
// ...
const boost::string_ref line_(line, line_length);
tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > line_tokenizer(
    line_, escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
```

and that seems to work. Read more about `string_ref` and the other utilities [here](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.utility).

Of course, if you have an implementation of the Guidelines Support Library, use `string_span` (a.k.a. `string_view`) from there ([here](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl-lite.h)'s one implementation). It's even making it into the standard library probably.

Update: `string_view` is in the C++ standard in C++17. Now you can write:

```
#include <string_view>
// ...
std::string_view line_ { line, line_length };
tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > line_tokenizer(
    line_, escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As compiler error says, there is no way to build iterator from const char*. You can fix it by use of std::string:

```
std::string line = "some string";
// ...
tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > line_tokenizer(
    line.begin(), line.end(),
    escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
```

Comment: This is in performance-critical code, so I don't want to start copying my strings into the std::string's buffer. I would use the GSL `string_view` or `string_span` or whatever they call it, but I don't want to include the entire GSL. Could you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Also, a lot of standard library algorithms take a pair of pointers as an iterator pair, e.g. `std::copy`; so why not this thing?

Comment: This tokenizer constructor takes Iterator (which is std::string::const_iterator actually), so you can't use raw char* pointers in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you have to build the token iterators manually if you don't want to use a container as the search space

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
    const char xx[] = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
    auto line = xx;
    size_t line_length = strlen(line);

    using namespace boost;

    auto f = escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"');
    auto beg = make_token_iterator<char>(line ,line + line_length,f);
    auto end = make_token_iterator<char>(line + line_length,line + line_length,f);
    // The above statement could also have been what is below
    // Iter end;
    for(;beg!=end;++beg){
        std::cout << *beg << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```